# Execute a command using a perl script

Tags: perl, unix, command-line

I have simple command in unix like

```
cat myfile.txt >&mytemp.txt&
```

The above command will simply create a copy of the file myfile.txt.
when i execute the command on the command line it returns me the process id like below:

```
> cat myfile.txt > & mytemp.txt &
[1] 769
>
```

I am forming the same command inside a perl script and calling it with system as below:

```
my $cmd="cat myfile.txt>&mytemp.txt&";
my $info = system("$cmd");
```

but the sytem command fails with the below error message:

```
sh: mytemp.txt: bad number
```

I even tried with escaping the `>` and `&`.But there is no change in the error message.
May i know the reason for this?where am i wrong here?

Comment: in my case the system command doesn't fail. I get the output 0. I'm printing `$info`.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? I suspect this isn't just copying a file, which you can do with File::Copy. Are you trying to launch a process in the background while continue running (In that case, do you want to get a signals from the process)? Do you just want to grab the output of a process and put in a file? Is the process you are running run for long time?

Comment: @Uri.You are right i am just trying to run a background process.I just need to get out of the process and continue executing the next statements .i dont even need anything in return after the process is run!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you can't use the trailing `&` on this.  If you want your program to continue while the command runs, then `fork` and have the child process run the call, then exit.  Possibly `exec` can do this, though I haven't tried doing that with output redirection before...

Comment: If you want to background the process fork is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I have process which throuws out put to console as well as a log file.If i want to suppress the output that is coming to the console i use `>&file&`.This is teh reason why i need to use the ampersand.I even tried with fork its running fine but its throws the output to console. and if i use `&>` and `&`,then even forking does not help as it again throwsa bad number error.

Comment: So the issue is that you want to capture STDERR and STDOUT for the process and redirect them to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Like the message says, that's not a valid `sh` command. Is it perhaps a `csh` command?

```
system('csh', '-c', $cmd);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
perl -e "`cat myfile.txt>&mytemp.txt&`;"
```

It's executing the command and returning the command output.
So it's possible to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $content = `cat /etc/passwd`;
print $content;
```

If you put the code into a perl script:

**cat-test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $res = `cat myfile.txt>&mytemp.txt&`;
```

Comment: Have you tried `cat myfile.txt>&mytemp.txt&` putting inside your perl script?